# Network Connection Type

Tags: ubuntu, networking, networkmanager

Is there way to determine if the LAN connection type is secure or insecure?
i.e., the Lan cable connected to machine is by [IEEE802.1X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X) or not ?

EDIT:

In Ubuntu 13.04, when I configure 802.1x security settings and plug the ethernet cable from 802.1x switch then I get the network through NetworkManager. Now, If I remove this cable and connect another normal cable then I do not get any network.

How NetworkManager manages this ?

Comment: So you want to know whether the connection is using EAP? That's a strange definition of “secure”.

Comment: Sometime, I run out of my English Vocabulary. Never mind. But I am happy you understand the question

Answer (score 1):

#### mii-tool?

You might be able to get this information from the device using the tool `mii-tool`.

#### Example

```
$ sudo mii-tool -v eth0
eth0: negotiated 100baseTx-FD flow-control, link ok
  product info: vendor 00:07:32, model 17 rev 2
  basic mode:   autonegotiation enabled
  basic status: autonegotiation complete, link ok
  capabilities: 1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD
  advertising:  100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
  link partner: 1000baseT-HD 1000baseT-FD 100baseTx-FD 100baseTx-HD 10baseT-FD 10baseT-HD flow-control
```

#### wpa_cli

The other tool that will likely give you this information is `wpa_cli`. It takes several options and you can query the running `wpa_supplicant` instance which is from what my research is showing, is what provides the 802.1X layer of security on top of the network connection.

I do not have access to this type of interface so could not work out an actual example but one of the commands will likely give you what you want:

```
$ wpa_cli status
```

Check the man page for wpa_cli for other options:

```
$ man wpa_cli
```

#### References

- [802.1X Port-Based Authentication HOWTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X)

Comment: I tried above mentioned commands. But it didn't do the job

Comment: @SHW In what way did they not do the job?

Comment: @SHW - can you do me a favor and clarify this a bit? You want to know what EAP protocol is being used or 802.11i? It's a bit confusing in the quagmire: http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/8021X-HOWTO/intro.html#what8021x

Comment: MichaelKjörling and slm, My apology if I am not clear on my question. What I want, is to know, whether Ethernet is connected by using EAP protocol or not.